# How does one calculate the energy of the impact of a punch?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

A punch collides (inelastically) with some object so how would one calculate the energy of the impact? How would one define the mass since "punch" isn't an object and how would one also define the velocity since, again, a "punch" isn't an object?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560503/what-is-the-input-for-the-mass-in-the-calculation-for-the-kinetic-energy-of-a-pu  and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560605/how-much-joules-should-a-punch-have-in-order-to-accomplish-the-following

Comment: Can you please help me calculate?

Comment: I can’t. Biomechanics is a messy topic and I have no expertise in it. I don’t really consider it part of physics at all.

Comment: It's much easier to measure the energy or momentum of a punch than to calculate it.

Comment: How would I measure the energy then?

Comment: When you say inelastically, you mean mass that causes the punch stays attached to the mass it "hits"?

Comment: No, the punch hits the mass, the mass fling some distance. They're not attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other questions you asked were inspired by an animated movie. A lot of what you see there is not explainable by physics - Many of the things you see just couldn't happen that way. So specific calculations might not be as useful as understanding some ideas. And you have extracted a reasonable physics question from it.

A punch does come from an object, a person. It is just not as simple an object as in most classroom physics problems. It has moving parts. We can try a few simplifications first.

Suppose you punched by throwing a fist that was not connected to an arm. If you know the mass and velocity, you can calculate the kinetic energy. $E = 1 /2 m v^2$

Add the arm. When you punch, you probably step forward. So the shoulder is moving at walking speed. The wrist is attached to the fist, which is going at punching speed. Parts in between move at intermediate speed. So you can see it is a bit complicated to calculate the kinetic energy of the arm. What you need to do is divide the arm into a lot of little pieces, figure out the speed of each piece, calculate the kinetic energy of each piece, and add up all the energies.

Finally, you add the rest of the body and do the same thing again. Various parts of the body are moving at different speeds, none very fast. But there is a lot of mass, so it adds to the kinetic energy.

That tells you how much energy is in you as you punch. But it isn't enough to tell you how hard you hit.

Suppose you went through the punching motion with a relaxed arm. How much of that kinetic energy would be transferred to your target? Energy is conserved. That means the total amount doesn't change. But it can be moved around and changed from one kind to another. So any kinetic energy left in you is not transferred to the target. With a relaxed arm, your fist and forearm come to a stop, but you keep going. Not much is transferred.

Suppose your arm was rigid like a statue. Then you and your fist would move at the same speed. You and your fist would come to a stop. All the energy would be transferred.

But a rigid arm isn't how it works either. Before you start a punch, you have no kinetic energy. You push your fist forward with your muscles. You convert some of the calories from food you ate into kinetic energy by pushing your body and your fist forward. Physicists talk about pushing in terms of force. As your fist connects, you continue pushing. So the total kinetic energy in you at the moment the punch lands isn't the total energy that goes into the punch. You generate more as you follow through.

But there is more about pushing as the punch lands. One of Newton's laws is that for every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction. This means for every force, there is an equal and opposite force. If you lean on someone and push, you don't just push him forward. You push yourselves apart. That is, as your arm pushes him forward, it also pushes you back.

This is important. This is how you transfer kinetic energy from yourself to your target. As you push him forward, he moves forward. As you push yourself back, you slow to a stop.

This is enough to see that it isn't as simple as how fast does your fist have to go. But there is more that I will just mention. Hitting a pillow is different from hitting a telephone pole. Also hitting something big is different from hitting something small. Instead of punching, think of baseball. You get one result if you hit a baseball, and another if you hit a bowling ball.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The punch **itself** doesn't collide and is as such not an object indeed. A punch has no mass and no velocity. It's a short force delivered by some object to another object (and vice-versa), so it **is** something physical.
This force has the value of $F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$, where $p$ is the total change in the momentum of both masses. To put it in another way, punches are involved in collisions between masses. Usually, in collision problems, the masses of two (or more) bodies, some of their initial (or final) momenta, and their initial (or final) energies are given, together with the condition of elasticity or non-elasticity (in which the kinetic energy of the masses has decreased after the collision). We can use the laws of conservation and energy to calculate the momenta and energies which are not given (of course in such a way that this is possible). But nothing is said about the Nature of the collision [except that the collision is (non) elastic], which is, in fact, punch-like. The Nature of these punches has its origin in the Nature of the material the masses are made of.
In the non-physical case where the masses are considered as point-particles, the punches become unphysical too: $F=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}\to \frac{dp}{dt}\to \infty$ which can't be the case obviously. This is ignored though, as well as the zero probability that these particles touch each other (I'm talking about classical, non-interacting particles) and only the facts I wrote before are given.
In the real world, every classical collision is non-elastic because every mass is deformed somehow during the collision, though collisions between billiard balls, for example, come close to being elastic. The punches take a short time.

You can imagine sending a soft object, say a sponge, with a very high momentum onto a metal ball. Clearly the collision is non-elastic. The kinetic energy of the sponge generates heat in the sponge, taking away a part of its kinetic energy. Depending on the mass of the metal ball, a part of the sponge's kinetic energy is given to the metal ball. By means of a punch that takes more time than in the case of billiard balls because the sponge is squeezed and stretched out again, which simply takes more time.

So if you know the mass of the impacting mass and is velocity, you also have to know the kinetic energy converted to the internal energy of the objects during the collision (which in exercise books on collisions is usually included in the collision being elastic or not). I'm not sure how to calculate this energy, but I know it's difficult (especially when the masses don't collide head-on, i.e. the line connecting their centers of mass doesn't lay on the line on which their momentum vectors lay). Calculating the kinetic energy given by a mass to another mass in an inelastic collision (you can also consider two sponges) is a difficult task, given only the masses and velocities of the two objects. For (approximately) elastic collisions, or two masses sticking together after they've made contact, this is easy though.

I know that I maybe have elaborated too much (which may confuse you), but I hope the concept of a punch it's somewhat clearer to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate both of you taking your time to help me:)