# Question about force of a blow from a wide flat surface

Tags: forces, pressure, momentum

Sometimes, when we surf the internet we always see something like bears, lions, tigers, etc. have bone-breaking paw swipes. While we know the weight of the animal and the speed play the role whether an animal can break bones with a blow, people always forget the structure of the thing that something used to blow something is important too. A club-shaped or rounded-shaped thing like a fist, an elbow or a knee attack can break bones if there is a considerable mass and speed behind the force because simply of the structure, while the paws of bears, tigers, and lions are wide and flat so it will be much harder to break bones despite the stories of those bone-crushing paw swipes. In fact, most of bone-breaking paw swipe stories are nothing more than anecdotes and not a single video demonstrated a bear or a lion killed something or breaking a bone with a paw swipe. So, a wide flat surface isn't appropriate to break hard tough objects such as a bone, stone, etc. Thoughts?

Comment: See [How does one calculate the energy of the impact of a punch?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560651/37364)

Comment: @mmesser314 my question is more about whether a flat and wide surface such as a paw can actually break a bone.

Answer (score 1):

Actually many factors play here.
Mass of the paw is important because greater the momentum( which is equal to product of mass and velocity ) greater the impulse(momentum transferred from one body to another).

Then the velocity is also essential in increasing momentum.

Moreover the time of contact is more important than maybe any factor because it determines the amount of force exerted. (Force = impulse / time) If the time is equal to the momentum no damage will be done since force becomes 1N. If the time period of impact is short, the damage can increase even with a short force.

Cross sectional area also plays a large role; directly affecting the pressure exerted.
Then cross sectional area of the paw is of course large as mentioned but, the cross sectional area of the region being hit is also a factor. e.g. a strike of a hockey can damage you much differently at the knee than at the thigh given the same force is applied.

These are the basic factors. Other minor factors may also play a role like the angle of impact etc.

In case of the "bone breaking" situation, it really depends where and how a person is hit.

Comment: Your bone breaking topic was a little unpleasant. :)

Comment: Yeah. Just out of curiosity. But between a baseball bat, a knee and a paw, the baseball will be the easiest to generate tremendous force followed by the knee and lastly the paw, due to the cross-sectional area. Isn't it? I can't see something wide and flat such as a slap or a paw can do enough damage to bones.

Comment: For your information animals are much more stronger. For instance experiments conducted on animals like gorillas showed they had capabilities to lift weights much heavier than those lifted by trained athletes. for example gorillas have proved to lift weights like 800kg and above while the deadlift world record is 500kg so if a gorilla did a deadlift you can imagine the difference. Thus, same for lions and other wild animals. They can in fact generate such a huge force that bones can break despite factors like paw area etc.

Comment: I hope my answer and comment was helpful enough.

Comment: I think the  pressure factor is the most important, i.e.  force per unit area.  That's why a giant paw will knock something over but the same total momentum in a pickaxe will drive a deep hole right into the object.

Comment: But the same total momentum is harder if not impossible for humans to produce. @CarlWitthoft

Comment: @FarisHassan  that wasn't what I was saying.  My point is that, for a given amount of force applied, the area of application matters a lot

Comment: Yes of course no doubt :)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft so a sledgehammer or a knee will generate enough force to break a bone than a paw or a open palmed hand. Correct?

Comment: @MohamedObeidallah It will exert more pressure not force. Force depends on a source of energy like a living thing. A sledgehammer or knee will exert more pressure given the same force is applied .i.e. force is constant and cross sectional area is changing.

Comment: I mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, many factors are in play, cross sectional area of paw being just one of those.

Comment: @FarisHassan then the less the area, the more likely the bone for example the vertebrae to break easily?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: But your question asked about the paw situation. Paws can break bones because animals are very strong, much stronger than they look.

Comment: @FarisHassan animals are strong of course but people always exaggerated them. There is not a single experiment conducting on how strong a gorilla is whether it is true a gorilla is 6 times stronger than a man or not. Carnivores break bones by biting, not hitting their prey.