# Calculating the damage done by a boxer's punch

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, estimation

I'm developing a VR boxing game and I'm curious about what would be the most accurate calculation to define a damage number for a boxer.

Right now I'm using Collision Response equation by putting values from the physics engine into this equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_response

So that I'm calculating the impulse value.

What would be a better way to do this? Another option to use seems using the boxer's hand mass, velocity, and angular velocity to calculate its kinetic energy. I also question which mass I should use, the hand or the whole arms mass.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Related - [How does one calculate the energy of the impact of a punch?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560651/37364)

Comment: Define Damage...